# Restart MongoDB Connecton on crash - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have server implemented using nodejs. According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656574/how-to-manage-mongodb-connections-in-a-nodejs-webapp), I have one single connection (using native MongoDB) in my `index.js` file which connects to the MongoDB on server start.

I am using forever, so each time the server crashes this module restarts it.

My question is: What will happen if my mongo connection will crash?  How can I handle this situation? How can I detect the crash programmatically? Should I restart it, if yes, how?

Comment: are you using mongoose.js?

Comment: @Kiran Pagar No, i am using native mongodb ( MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient). http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html

Comment: For mongoose, you can use something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342904/error-no-open-connections-at-db-executequerycommand-node-js/29347440#29347440 - There must be some similar way to go about this with native too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set auto-connect parameter as true.

```
app.use(session({
store: new MongoStore({
    // Basic usage
    host: 'localhost', // Default, optional
    port: 27017, // Default, optional
    db: 'test-app', // Required

    // Basic authentication (optional)
    username: 'user12345',
    password: 'foobar',

    // Advanced options (optional)
    autoReconnect: true, // Default

})
```

}));

Comment: Thank you, i will use this.